# How to redefine JS function keeping previous in chain

Tags: javascript

This is common task coming from object oriented programming, I would like to change behavior of JavaScript program by overriding existing function with possible calling it as well. I remember Windows introduced that as writing hooks and chaining them. So what I want, I have a web page which calls some onload hook which finally calls function initFields. I want to redefine this function however keep previous implementation. If I simply define my JS function as

```
function initFields() {
  // do some stuff ...
   // I do not know how to call super.initFields() here
}
```

I read something like you can write

```
initFields.prototype = function() {
     // do some stuff ...
     // but still have no idea how to call the original one
 };
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Show us an example of how the original function is declared, how it is used, how yours is used, etc.

Answer (score 6):

One option is

```
var initFieldsInitial = initFields;
function initFields() {
   // your stuff
   initFieldsInitial.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: You can also back up existing functions into variables.  `var oldFunc = obj.func; obj.func = new function() {...; oldFunc.apply(this, arguments); };`

Comment: It looks like initFieldsInitial got address of the redefined initFields in context, so I got looped, but I like the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the wrap() function from the underscore.js library.

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#wrap

```
var initFields = function() {
    // do something
    console.log('initFields');
}

initFields = _.wrap(initFields, function(initial) {
    // do some stuff
    console.log('wrapper');
    initial();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    initFields();
});
```